# Firebase search nested children

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase structure like this:
[image]

I want to search based on name. It has 2 push keys on its path.
Is it possible to search firebase with nested children having more than 1 push keys.
Expecting the answers only using firebase rest api.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can search on a property at a fixed path under the child nodes of the location where you execute the query. This means that in your current data model you cannot filter users on the name of one of their groups. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: No comments, Really regret the decision to use firebase

Comment: Most NoSQL databases have more limited query capabilities than what you may be used to if you come from a SQL background. This is not laziness by their providers, but a conscious choice to favor scalability over the query capabilities of the system. Firebase further favors the ability to efficiently synchronize the data for a query between connected clients. If you don't need the scalability and realtime aspects, you may be better served by a more traditional database.